# Apache LogFormat: log full domain name all the time

Tags: apache-http-server, logging

We have one server that hosts many different domains. As this server is phased out, we want to know if there are still domains pointing to this server. I would like to have the Apache logs report these domain names.

Our Apache logs show the following data:

> 163.172.66.133 - - [16/Dec/2016:11:37:40 +0100] "GET /en/page/test HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"

It should be with the full domain name of the requested page.

> 163.172.66.133 - - [16/Dec/2016:11:37:40 +0100] "GET https://**www.domainname.com**/en/page/test HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"

I use the following LogFormat:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%m http://%v:%p%U\" %>s %b" common
```

Sometimes I see the full domain name, most of the time not.

**How can I have the domain names displayed all the time?**

Comment: By using the right [log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html). Most likely you want to include `%v` or `%V`.

Comment: What happens if the servername or alias does not define all domain names?

Comment: How would that happen? If you look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) you need to either have a domain or IP defined in order for the server to respond. This way you would know which server responded and other requests should not be responded to. The location in your question does only contain the GET request header part and that might just not include the domain. One option to always have that would be to only have absolute links on your site (undesirable).

Comment: I just noticed you already have `%v` in your `LogFormat` are you sure this is your only definition in all the host configurations? Have a look at that question: [Using %v in Apache LogFormat definition matches ServerName instead of specific vhost requested](http://serverfault.com/questions/133711/using-v-in-apache-logformat-definition-matches-servername-instead-of-specific-v) it would suggest you could also use `%{Host}` which might give you the information you're looking for?

Comment: These domains are not defined. The links are relative, so the GET only displays that. Using `%{Host}i` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: So your server just servers random domains? After all you have to have some configuration that allows those requests to reach it, right? What does `%{Host}` generate?

Comment: Not just random domains, but too many to configure. It seems to work now. We had more LogFormat items, and I thought one was not used, but after changing that one the domain name displays on all log items. If you want th points, make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) for the log format you will see that the flag `%v` or `%V` might be what you're interested in as it would give you the Canonical ServerName that is configured. So it would be the ServerName configured in the block that finally responded to the request.

As the `LogFormat` line you supplied already contains that identifier it is likely that more than one configuration exists that sets the log format and the log lines that don't contain the host are based on that different format. Your format should get you always line that are formatted like your second example.

What could still be an issue is that you have configured wildcard domains and you would not be able to see which complete FQDN was requests. A question titled [Using %v in Apache LogFormat definition matches ServerName instead of specific vhost requested](https://serverfault.com/questions/133711/using-v-in-apache-logformat-definition-matches-servername-instead-of-specific-v) would suggest that you could use the identifier `%{Host}` to get the "client perspective" so the host part of the request header.

To find all configuration files that contain a `LogFormat` line you could have a look at another question like the following one: [How to find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-to-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)